# Java email with Gmail behaving differently within Eclipse/Maven vs in a packaged jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gmail, starttls

I've had this "Gmail.java" class based on javax.mail that has been working for a while for sending email through a Gmail account.

Lately, I've discovered Maven and I am starting all my new projects using it.

On this latest project (using a Maven archetype), for some reason the following property needs to be turned on or off whether I want to run the program within Eclipse or from a deployed jar :

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

If this line is present when I run inside Eclipse, I get the "PKIX path building failed" exception that is often mentioned in StackOverflow questions.  Then if I package my app and run it from some linux shell, all is fine and the email is sent.

On the other hand, if I comment the line, the email will be sent when run within Eclipse, and if I package and deploy, I'd then get a runtime error about SSL being needed to talk to Gmail.

Here's my pom.xml, I suppose the cause could be in there ?!?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Name</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-my-bundle</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.htmlcleaner</groupId>
        <artifactId>HtmlCleaner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
        <artifactId>imagecomparison</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stevesoft.pat</groupId>
        <artifactId>pat</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```